# How can I deal with form in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to deal with form to update data in animal table but it is not showing any error but do not save at all.

Here is my form create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Add Animal')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Farm</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Welcome {{ $user->name }} Please Add an animal</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form action="/farm" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dateOfBirth">Date Of Birth: </label>
                    <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                </div>
                <div class="pb-5">
                    {{ $errors->first('dateOfBirth') }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="placeOfBirth">Place Of Birth</label>
                    <input type="text" name="placeOfBirth" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
                    <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                        <option value="M">Male</option>
                        <option value="F">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Farm</button>

                @csrf
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

And my FarmController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Animal;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FarmController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $animal = Animal::all();
        return view('farm.index', compact('animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = new Animal();
        return view('farm.create', compact('user', 'animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $animal = Animal::create($this->validateRequest());

        event(new NewAnimalRegisteredEvent($animal));

       // Mail::to($customer->email)->send(new WelcomeNewUserMail());

        return redirect('farm.show');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param Animal $animal
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Animal $animal)
    {
        return view('farm.show', compact('animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    private function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'farmer_id' => 'required',
            'dateOfBirth' => 'required|date',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'placeOfBirth' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
}
```

my Animal model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Animal extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function clinicdetail(){
        return $this->hasOne(ClinicDetail::class);
    }

    public function slaughterdetail(){
        return $this->hasOne(SlaughterDetail::class);
    }
}
```

user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id',
    ];

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
    public function animal(){
        return $this->hasMany(Animal::class);
    }

    public function clinicdetail(){
        return $this->hasMany(ClinicDetail::class);
    }

    public function slaughterdetail(){
        return $this->hasMany(SlaughterDetail::class);
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

My routes

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {

    // All your admin routes go here.



      Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController');
    });

    Route::middleware('farm')->group(function () {

        // All your admin routes go here.
        Route::resource('/farm', 'FarmController');
    });

    Route::middleware('clinic')->group(function () {

        // All your admin routes go here.
        Route::resource('/clinic', 'ClinicController');
    });

    Route::middleware('slaughter')->group(function () {

        // All your admin routes go here.
        Route::resource('/slaughter', 'SlaughterController');
    });





Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

and lastely my event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewAnimalRegisteredEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $animal;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($animal)
    {
        $this->animal = $animal;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Kindly assist me with this one. It bringing the url assign in the store method but it is not saving the animal

Comment: what actually happens when you submit the form? the `store` method's redirect is gonna be an interesting URL

Comment: Like nothing happens, no error

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic

```
public function store()
    {
        $animal = Animal::create($this->validateRequest());

        event(new NewAnimalRegisteredEvent($animal));

       // Mail::to($customer->email)->send(new WelcomeNewUserMail());

        return redirect('farm.show');
    }
```

is called by submitting your form and is calling an event. This is event however does not have the required handle function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#defining-listeners
Your event as it is now does nothing. It looks like you try to broadcast, but it does not implement `ShouldBroadcast` and you should also check if you meet [all the requirements for broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites). I hope this helps and maybe should be a comment, however the text is too long to be a comment. I can edit this answer as needed when provided with more info.

Comment: there could potentially be a listener defined in the `EventServiceProvider` for it but who knows

Comment: @lagbox Good catch, I hope Jimmyjbk can specify if that's the case. For now I try to help by analysing the current provided information. I just like to help new users that do their best providing this level of info. :)

Comment: I cannot understand what exactly wrong with the code

Comment: @Jimmyjbk Why don't you start with something simpler without using events and just directly saving